# Installing Chrome for an application using Selenium on a remote server Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, google-chrome

I'll need to run a python application using a google chrome selenium 16 on a remote server on Ubuntu. Is it possible at all, doesn't it require a display?
If it is, how can I install a  google chrome for selenium? Should I install the normal google chrome and will it be installed automatically? If not, then how can I do that?

```
$ uname -a
Linux name123 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to make a setup for Behavior Driven Development in Wordpress/PHP through the AWS cloud using Ubnutu16. Basically the same thing you're doing except I'm using PHP. I USED to be able to do this with older versions of Selenium2 and Mink, but with the new versions I'm having no joy. These directions are currently incomplete but will get you as far as having a working GUI that you can access. This setup uses [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) to have a GUI on the remote Amazon instance, even though the instance is in the cloud:

[Behavior Driven Development for WordPress with AWS and Codeception](http://customrayguns.com/bdd-wp-aws/)

My current problem is that I can get Selenium up and running, but I can't get the PHP bindings to drive the browsers. Mink or Facebook aren't working. I think it has something to do with the security settings. I'll edit this when I know more. You can probably get the Python bindings to work with this setup. Good luck!

Comment: Is this an answer to the OP?

Comment: Partial. We're both trying to run Selenium with a GUI on Ubuntu in the cloud. There aren't any complete working tutorials. Improve my answer and I'll retract--- please! :)